# Format String Vertically

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

I am receiving such data with python that comes as a string from firebase database. How can I format it into more readable data for the user?

**Received Output**

`{'date': '07-Oct-2019', 'day': 'Monday', 'driver': 'John '}`

**Desired OutPut**

```
date   : 07-Oct-2019 
day    : Monday
driver : jop
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple one line should do

```
d={'date': '07-Oct-2019', 'day': 'Monday', 'driver': 'John '}
print("\n".join([k+":"+v for k,v in d.items()]))
```